# Declare uninitialized auto variables with type of Returning function

Tags: c++, auto, decltype-auto

I am a fan of using `auto` as much as possible, but there's one scenario where so far I have no solution.

The scenario is where I have to declare the variable outside of a scope, but initialize it inside a scope, typically a `try/catch`. Here is a clasical example:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Some::Custom::Type> Initialize()
{
    return {};
}

void Use()
{
    // delctype(Initialize) result; // not working
    // auto result; // completely different
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Some::Custom::Type> result // so much typing
    try
    {
        result = Initialize();
    }
    catch(...) {}
    ....
    
}
```

PS. I know that you can avoid the issue by doing the rest of the code inside the `try` scope, but sometimes you need it like this.
Is there a way to achieve `delctype(Initialize) result;` idiom in up to C++20?

Comment: If it's a type that you have to use many times can't you just `#define` or `typedef`a shorter macro for it and use that?

Comment: it's a generic case, sometimes it's a vector, a string, a ptr, whatever function I might call in a large codebase.

Comment: @AndreiM What about decltype( Initialize() ) result;

Comment: Use lambda directly invoked?

Comment: `decltype(Initialize()) result;` works: https://godbolt.org/z/KvY3r6sPq

Answer (score 2):

`decltype(Initialize)` is the type of the function. You want `decltype(Initialize())` to get the type of the expression `Initialize()`, which is simply the return type:

```
decltype(Initialize()) result;
```

You might also use an immediately invoked lambda:

```
auto result = []{
    try
    {
        return Initialize();
    }
    catch(...) {}
}();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dqWY9q7cM)

Other options include making a type alias to shorten it, using [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) (though I don't think this has any benefit over `decltype` in this context), or, as you mention, having the rest of the code inside the try block; you can even put the entire function inside with a [function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block).

Comment: any insights on how to handle an `Initialize` method with parameters?

Comment: capture, or pass parameter to the lambda?

Comment: @AndreiM What stops you from passing parameters? [Here's an example](https://godbolt.org/z/nKbWT1493).

Answer (score 0):

You basically have three approaches.

#### 1. `decltype`

Give `decltype` an actual expression of the type your variable should have:  `delctype(Initialize())`. Note: this is not always practical when the function takes a lot of parameters.

```
struct long_name {};

long_name initialize() { return {}; }

int main()
{
    decltype(initialize()) value;
    {
        value = initialize();
    }
}
```

([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6d9T56Yv))

---

#### 2. `std::invoke_result`

There is also [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) if you want to construct an elaborate trait.

---

#### 3. Type alias

As an ultimate alternative, a type alias is sometimes the better solution:

```
using Types = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Some::Custom::Type>;
```

Comment: thank you. Approach 1 is what I actually wanted, and I was close, I just missed the paranthesis. However, if the method has some parameters, we're back to square 1: https://godbolt.org/z/rPseKGeT1